# python + linux + not killing subprocess issues

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, os.path

I am trying to find out a list of files within a directory path, which were created within the past 'n' minutes, using subprocess.popen with 'find' linux command.

```
def Subprocessroutine(n,path):
     argf='find '+str(path)+' -maxdepth 1 -mmin -'+str(n)+' -type f -printf "\n%AD %AT %p" | sort'
     p=subprocess.Popen(argf,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
     soutput,sinput=p.communicate()
     return soutput
```

Since i am using a simple find command (with formatting and sort), do i need to make sure i kill the subprocess explicitly?.

The reason i am using the 'find' command is :
I need a list of files created in the past 'n' minutes and the result should in the file creation sorted order (I am unable to get this using the following code):

```
for p, ds, fs in os.walk(dirpath):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)
        if os.path.getmtime(filepath) >= n:
            print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filepath)))
```

Is there a better way to get the result, without using the subprocess?.

My final output should look like this:

```
09/26/1619:41:04.4865673390 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST39_2016-09-26 19:40:03.283121_2016-09-26 19:41:03.283109.csv
09/26/1619:41:04.4875673570 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST40_2016-09-26 19:40:03.283561_2016-09-26 19:41:03.283552.csv
09/26/1619:41:04.4885673750 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST41_2016-09-26 19:40:03.283988_2016-09-26 19:41:03.283980.csv
09/26/1619:41:04.4895673930 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST42_2016-09-26 19:40:03.284408_2016-09-26 19:41:03.284399.csv
09/26/1619:41:04.4905674110 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST43_2016-09-26 19:40:03.284852_2016-09-26 19:41:03.284843.csv
09/26/1619:41:04.4915674290 /home/Testing/Input/Sep26/HST44_2016-09-26 19:40:03.285295_2016-09-26 19:41:03.285288.csv
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you tried? See my answer

Comment: @urban The second part of your answer was perfect. I could not get the result List in 'file creation' sorted order using os.path. Sorting the result list solved it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pynood :) no worries, have a look at epoch time and I m sry I used a `lambda` (I tend to not like them...) but in this case is exactly what you needed - let me know if you have questions on the answer's comments and I can clarify more.

Comment: @urban I had actually used the sort option on a list of lists further down in my program!. It just did not occur to me as an option at this point of the code. It's only been a few months of python coding for me (coming from a Mainframe background!!). The option to sort the contents of a list is some thing i find very useful. Will keep this option in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the only thing that "did not work" was the fact that dead links cause it to throw an `OSError`. I have modified it to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import datetime

dirpath = "./"

for p, ds, fs in os.walk(dirpath):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)
        # This catches bad links!
        try:
            if os.path.getmtime(filepath) >= time.time() - 30*60:
                dt_mod = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filepath))
                print("Adding   %s - %s" % (str(dt_mod), filepath))
            else:
                print("Skipping %s - %s" % (str(dt_mod), filepath))
        except OSError as e:
            print("Arrrgggg: %s" % str(e))
```

Note that `time.time() - 30*60` is current time minus 30 minutes, where `time.time()` gives you the current time as `float`. I am running in `/tmp` folder... the result is:

> ```
> $ python ./test.py 
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./test.py
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./qtsingleapp-homeur-6219-3e8-lockfile
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./.X0-lock
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./urban.socket
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./config-err-yVuRIy
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:24.913770 - ./qtsingleapp-homeur-6219-3e8
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./.com.vivaldi.Vivaldi.82Dchr/SingletonSocket
> Arrrgggg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './.com.vivaldi.Vivaldi.82Dchr/SingletonCookie'
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./ksocket-urban/klauncherhX3020.slave-socket
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./ksocket-urban/KSMserver__0
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./ksocket-urban/kdeinit4__0
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./skype-3294/DbTemp./temp-vL1IkSGDS19DRPp35idqPr9i
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./skype-3294/DbTemp./temp-oBEOkqraeZoXoyOrtvgzyxgE
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./skype-3294/DbTemp./temp-urolswo9ukl5kCzrRAD3epUw
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:19:53.685688 - ./skype-3294/DbTemp./temp-u5xJMdmkGEwV7K1nhqzx9Jg0
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./kde-urban/konsole-Jw4443.history
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:48:25.661770 - ./kde-urban/konsole-tX4539.history
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:48:25.661770 - ./kde-urban/konsole-SK4539.history
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:48:25.661770 - ./kde-urban/konsole-Jt4539.history
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:48:25.661770 - ./kde-urban/xauth-1000-_0
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./kde-urban/konsole-cq4443.history
> Adding   2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./kde-urban/konsole-WK4443.history
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./gpg-t0jSN1/S.gpg-agent
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./.X11-unix/X0
> Skipping 2016-09-26 19:44:48.309759 - ./.ICE-unix/3044
> ```

I am not sorting or storing the results but this is easily doable...

#### EDIT

The sorting part involves storing the results that we like and printing them after sorting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import datetime

dirpath = "./"

results = []

for p, ds, fs in os.walk(dirpath):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)
        # This catches bad links!
        try:
            if os.path.getmtime(filepath) >= time.time() - 30*60:
                dt_mod = os.path.getmtime(filepath)
                print("Adding   %s - %s" % (str(dt_mod), filepath))
                results.append((filepath, os.path.getmtime(filepath)))
            else:
                print("Skipping %s - %s" % (str(dt_mod), filepath))
        except OSError as e:
            print("Arrrgggg: %s" % str(e))


results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for s in results:
    print(s)
```

I have removed `datetime` conversions since the result can be produced using only `epoch` timestamps